# Getting started on buildout for Django

Tags: django, deployment, buildout

Can someone help me get started on buildout for python Django projects?

My primary objective is to deploy applications to the developer, staging and production boxes.

Examples or pointers to opensource projects appreciated.

Comment: you can check http://http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/

Comment: What did you try so far, what problems did you encounter? Better to ask specific, directed questions! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paulo's comment above to check http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/ is the first place you'll have to look.

If you use django with buildout, you just cannot live without the "djangorecipe" extension for buildout: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorecipe

And, just to give you an example **to get started with**, I'd suggest:

```
$> sudo easy_install nensskel
$> nensskel -t nens_lizardsite test-site
```

And then you can look at the test-site directory for a couple of tricks (buildout.cfg in combination with a deploy.cfg, a settings.py plus a developmentsettings.py and so on).

(Nensskel is just a company-internal basic site/app/library generator I made, but it is instructive as an example to get you started with your own setup).

Comment: confused a bit: what's nensskel?

Comment: See the last paragraph: a generator that generates a bunch of code. Basically a full site/app directory with setup.py, models.py etc. (Oh: perhaps installing it in a virtualenv is handier: easier to throw away later).